# java servlet connect with postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets

I have some problems with connect java servlet with postgresql .
help me if you can ,please

```
String dbName = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/schedule_of_holidays";
        String dbDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver";

        Class.forName(dbDriver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName, userName,
                password);
        System.out.println("Got Connection");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select id from registration";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt("id"));
        }
```

Comment: `I have some problems ` ??? please tell at least one problem.

Comment: What errors are you seeing ? Only possible error i am seeing is `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Lemme guess: You're running on Tomcat 7, but you didn't put the postgreSQL JDBC driver JAR in the Tomcat /lib folder, so you're getting a ClassNotFoundException when you try to load the driver.

Comment: Can you please add the exception here.

Comment: Heinous code.  You aren't really going to something with this, are you?  No connection pool, no externalized connection info, SQL in servlet instead of POJO DAO.  Very poor.

Comment: I don't have exception but I couldn't to connect with db.

Comment: Oh, there's an exception.  Did you look in the logs?  Or the console?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code and remember one thing before running the code that you have added the `postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar` in your lib folder at the following location: `tomcat_home/webapps/<project_name>/WEB-INF/lib`

Without this jar file, you got the `ClassNotFoundException`

```
         String dbName = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/struts_new";
         String dbDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
         String userName = "postgres";
         String password = "postgres"; 

         try{
         Class.forName(dbDriver);
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName, userName, password);
         System.out.println("Got Connection");
         Statement statement = con.createStatement();
         String sql = "select * from login";
         ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
         while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getString("uname"));
         }
         }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Hope this code helps you.